# add xml node at the first of the it's parent node

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<users>
  <user>
    <firstname>Mark</firstname>
    <surname>Zhu</surname>
    </user>
</users>
```

this is the user node I want to add in the front of the existing one

```
  <user>
<firstname>Andy</firstname>
<surname>Li</surname>
</user>
```

The SimpleXMLElement::addChild can add the in the back of the existing one, 
Is there anybody know how to add in the front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use DOM, in particular

```
DOMNode::insertBefore(DOMNode, DOMNode)
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php

Comment: This is a good solution. BTW the Does simpleXMLElement class belong to DOMNode class?

Comment: A quick glance at the documentation tells me they're separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

What if you read the xml then in a new document, printed your user node + the original xml?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to simply add the xml-declaration by hand. You can simply output it before the xml structure.